# Tim doesn't trust his roommates not to finish his breakfast

Tags: no-not

I don't know the meaning of this sentence below. Could anyone help? Thanks!

**"Tim doesn't trust his roommates not to finish his breakfast."**

Context: Tim is having a confidential phone call in the kitchen. His roommates are in the living room, where they can hear what he says on the phone. All of them are having breakfast on their own.

I guess the meaning is that "Because Tim doesn't finish his breakfast, he stays in the kitchen. However, he does not trust his roommates." Is that correct?

Comment: Tim doesn't want to go to another room as he believes that if he leaves his breakfast unattended, his roommates will eat (finish) his breakfast whilst he is gone.

Comment: @JonLarby I get it now. Thank you soooo much for the instant reply!

Comment: Replace *finish* with other verbs, it will make sense. E.g. *not to steal his breakfast*

Comment: Take out the two negatives and you get "Tim trusts his roommates to finish his breakfast".  That's not the exact meaning - but it's close to it.

Answer (score 2):

When you *don't trust someone to do something* it means you want them to do that thing but you don't think they will. Here, the *something* is *not finishing [Tim's] breakfast*, so:

Tim wants his friends to *not finish his breakfast* but is worried that they *<s>won't not</s> **will** finish his breakfast* where I replaced the double-negative.